# Prolog - creating cumulative duplicates in a list?

Tags: list, prolog, duplicates

I have a list `L` given and my task is to create cumulative duplicates, depending on how many I want.

I have the list `[a,b,c,d]` for example and want the first element to be duplicated 4 times (optional), then every subsequent element has to be duplicated like the previous one + 1.

Let's assume my predicate is called `list_copy(L,N,R)`, the result with `L = [a,b,c,d]` and `K = 2` should be:

```
?- list_copy([a,b,c,d],2,R).
R = [a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,d,d,d,d,d]
```

I've managed to create a universal code for duplicating a list two times:

```
dupl([],[]).
dupl([O|U],[O,O|U1]) :- dupl(U,U1).
```

Depending on how many `O`'s I put in my second line I get that many duplicates.

My question is, though: How can I implement a 3rd variable as a cumulative counter, in order to get the desired outcome?

Comment: As much as I want to give you the answer: consider adding a predicate n_of(N, Element, List) that would give you a List of N times Element like this:
    `?- n_of(2, a, L).`
    `L = [a,a]`

Comment: @SpinyNorman It would be even better if `n_of` had 4 arguments instead of 3, for a difference list. Otherwise, `n_of/3` is as simple as `length(L, N), maplist(=(Element), L)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have to "count" stuff one by one, consider using `succ/2`. It has the nice property that it works both ways, and fails when you call it with `succ(X, 0)`.

So first, the predicate that does "cumulative duplicates":

```
cum_dup([], _, []).
cum_dup([X|Xs], N, Ys) :-
    repeat_n(X, N, Ys, Back),
    succ(N, N1),
    cum_dup(Xs, N1, Back).
```

This uses the predicate `repeat_n/4`, which takes an elements, a non-negative integer, and repeats the element. It leaves a "hole" in the back of the list that you can fill with the rest of the result using `cum_dup/3`. Here is a straight-forward implementation of `repeat_n/4`:

```
repeat_n(_, 0, L, L).
repeat_n(X, N, [X|Xs], Rest) :-
    succ(N0, N),
    repeat_n(X, N0, Xs, Rest).
```

This will already give you the result you need:

```
?- cum_dup([a,b,c,d], 2, R).
R = [a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c, c, d, d, d, d, d] ;
false
```

It leaves behind a harmless choice point. There are too many ways to make a `repeat_n/4` that does not leave unnecessary choice points:

- use CLP(FD)
- use a cut
- use a conditional (if-then-else)
- use a structure instead of an integer

Just one example:

```
repeat_n(X, N, L, Back) :-
    length(Ns, N),
    repeat_n_(Ns, X, L, Back).

repeat_n_([], _, L, L).
repeat_n_([_|Ns], X, [X|Xs], L) :-
    repeat_n_(Ns, X, Xs, L).
```

Here, instead of counting with an integer, you (ab)use a list of that length.

I guess you can think about it yourself and ask another question if you really need to.

Answer (score 1):

**--- EDIT ---** modified using `succ/2`, as suggested by Boris (thanks!).

I suppose you can use a helper clause. Like `list_copy_h/4` in the following example

```
list_copy_h([], _, _, []).

list_copy_h([_ | Tin], 0, Num, Lout) :-
  succ(Num, Np1),
  list_copy_h(Tin, Np1, Np1, Lout).

list_copy_h([H | Tin], Count, Num, [H | Tout]) :-
  succ(Cm1, Count),
  list_copy_h([H | Tin], Cm1, Num, Tout).

list_copy(Lin, Num, Lout) :-
  list_copy_h(Lin, Num, Num, Lout).
```

The idea is use a counter (the second argument) that decrease to zero. When zero, the head of the input list is discharged and the cycle begin again with the following element of the input list but increasing the starting value of the counter. The third argument is the starting value.

Comment: You can replace `N > 0, N0 is N - 1` with `succ(N0, N)`.

Comment: @Boris - Very useful; thanks! I didn't know that `succ/2` was only for non negative integers. Unfortunately my gprolog (a old version) doesn't support it.

Comment: @maq66: In GNU Prolog, you can easily program `succ/2` with CLP(FD) constraints!

Comment: Strange. It says, "succ(X, Y) is true iff Y is the successor of the non-negative integer X". Or do you mean that you are not using 1.4.4? (This was released in 2013 btw)

Comment: @Boris - exactly: I'm using gprolog 1.3.0. Unfortunately, Debian packages only this old version (in sid too!).

Comment: @mat - Yes... I'm not good with CLP(FD) in prolog but I'll try. Thanks for the suggestion.